# Cannot get certain Respond Header

Tags: post, http-headers, jsreport

I am using Jsreport via API.

From the browser, a ajax call is made to jsreport server. The server answers with POST respond with data and a Header tag Permanent-Link which has the file location.

Copy paste it to the browser allow me to view the PDF file.

The problem it that I want to view it automatically in success handler of ajax call, but `xhr.getRespondHeader()` does not allow any other header than Content-Type. The respond header even have "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" already.

How can I get the PDF out for user?

Answer (score 1):

You can use official jsreport browser client - http://jsreport.net/learn/browser-client

If it is loaded in the page, opening a report is as simple as this

```
jsreport.serverUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';

var request = {
  template: { 
    content: 'foo', engine: 'none', recipe: 'phantom-pdf'
   }
};

//display report in the new tab
jsreport.render('_blank', request);
```

You can also check its source code if you are curious how it is handling AJAX 
https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport-browser-client-dist

Comment: I followed your website and see  bothjsclient and jsembed. Are they the same?

Comment: embed.js was deprecated and is not part of jsreport@1 default installation